# Unable to connect to SMB server after Mojave update 10.14.5

Tags: macos, windows, mojave, smb

I used to be able to connect to a shared folder on a local Windows PC from my MacBook Air (Early 2015) by doing `Finder > Go > Connect to Server` or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and then typing `smb://hostname/folder` and connecting as *Guest*.

This method worked without fail for years but it suddenly doesn't work anymore since the Mojave update 10.14.5 (18F132). I can still get to the name/password prompt as usual, but after I pick *Guest* and click *Connect* I get the following error:

> There was a problem connecting to the server "*hostname*".
>
> Check the server name or IP address, and then try again. If you continue to have problems, contact your system administrator.

- I have tried to reboot both machines, without success
- The same thing happens when I try to connect with an actual user account instead of *Guest*
- The same thing happens when I use the server's IP address instead of *hostname*
- The server can be pinged
- The server doesn't show up in Finder's Network page

To confirm this is a mac-side issue I installed the *FE File Explorer* app on my iPhone and was able to instantly find the server and connect to the shared folder as *Guest*.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: See if this works: https://swissmacuser.ch/workaround-connecting-smb-fileshare-in-macos-mojave/

Comment: @IconDaemon Yes this works to properly mount the folder with a username/password. However Guest doesn't work and the server still doesn't show up in Finder's Network view. Thanks for helping!